# Properties of 4 by 4 Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Define

$    
A=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & 0 & 0\\
0 &1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}, 
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
x_3 &x_4&x_5&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix},
C=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 &1&0&0\\
0&x_6&x_7&x_8\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix},$

$
D=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 &1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&x_9&x_{10}
\end{pmatrix}$.

Let  $W$ be a product of above matrices. (For example $ W $ can be $D^2ABDC$ or $CAD$ (any product of above matrices)).

Now define reverse of $W$ as $Re(W)$. For example if $W=D^2ABDC$ then $Re(W)=CDBAD^2$, If $W=CAD$ then $Re(W)=DAC$.

I want to prove $\det(W+Re(W))-\det(W-Re(W))$ is divisible by $4$. In other words $\det(W+Re(W))-\det(W-Re(W))\equiv 0 \mod 4$.

Any comment really appreciated.

**Note (Grumpy Parsnip):** A generalized phenomenon seems to be true here. One can define $n\times n$ matrices of a similar form. E.g. $A_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc} x_1&x_2\\0&1\end{array}\right)$ and $B_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\x_3&x_4\end{array}\right)$. Then it seems that for $2m\times 2m$ matrices,

$$\det(W+Re(W))+(-1)^{m-1}\det(W-Re(W))=0\mod 4.$$

Perhaps the $2\times 2$ case is easier to understand. I'll award a bounty for a solution to the $2\times 2$ case. (Hopefully the OP, who is a friend of mine, will not mind my edits.)

Comment: You want to prove that $4$ is a common factor of what and what?

Comment: Velcome to our site!  You should however edit your post to make it less unclear what the question is.

Comment: Note that the congruence is trivial (mod $2$), since $W+Re(W) = W-Re(W)$ (mod $2$). So you only need one more factor of $2$.

Comment: I assume you want $x_1,x_2,x_3...$ to be integers?

Comment: This statement does seem to be empirically true.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip WLOG you may as well assume that $x_i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$

Comment: The OP emailed me to mention that $x_i\in\mathbb Z[t]$. Apparently he can't comment on his own posts since he has less than 50 rep!

Comment: OP shouldn't comment on the post anyway. OP should *edit* the post so it says what it's actually intended to say.

Comment: I wrote a mathematica program that verified this for all products $W$ of five or fewer matrices.

Comment: Sorry if what I am saying is something silly but I do not understand why Re($W$) is well defined

Comment: @user90041: $Re(W)$ is defined as an operation on words, not on matrices.

Comment: [Check this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_matrices). It will make easy to manipulate $\large 4\times 4$ matrices.

Comment: Judging by some results from the 2x2 case, it looks like this might remain valid if Re($W$) was replaced by any permutation of $W$...

Comment: @Semiclassical No you cannot replace Re(W) with any permutation of W. For example if W=ABCD and if we replace Re(W) by BDCA then it do not satisfy the conjecture. Another example is W=ABCD^2 and Re(W) is replaced by BAD^2C this also do not satisfy conjecture. So Re(W) cannot replace by permutations of W

Answer (score 3):

My impulse is to prove it by induction (on the number of factors in $W$).  Clearly the result holds for any single-factor products.  So, assuming that the result holds for $W$, show that $\det(AW+WA)\equiv \det(AW-WA)\mod 4$, and similarly for $B,C$, and $D$.  Just doing the algebra by hand, I showed that it's true at least for $A$.  I assume the others would work out somewhat similarly.  At the very least, the calculation for $D$ would be symmetric.

Comment: Shouldn't you be considering $AW\pm Re(W)A$?

Comment: Okay, I agree with you that for all matrices $W$, $\det(AW+WA)= \det(AW-WA)\mod 4$. I can't believe you did that by hand! I checked it using mathematica.

Comment: But it's not obvious how this helps I guess.

Comment: Isn't it?  I mean, it seems like how you'd go about doing a proof by induction on the length of the product W.  The idea is that if you can add any one of the four (I admit I only did the calculation for A) at a time, then the result holds for words of arbitrary length.

Comment: I did the calculation for all 4 and it works, but show me how that proves the result for $w=ABC$.

Comment: Another way to say it is that the operation $AW\mapsto WA$ preserves the cyclic order of the word, so it won't be able to get you from $w$ to $Re(w)$.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking wrong.  So I guess you'd have to do Re(W)*A, and it's not so obvious how to calculate Re(W) without knowing more about W.

Answer (score 3):

> **Added 2014-07-14:** The Answer below is a **rewrite of the former text** which was essentially just an *approach to a possible solution*. It was based upon the idea to interpret the matrices $A_2$ and $B_2$ as *transformation matrices for an automaton*. The language which is generated by this automaton could then be analysed to find the solution.
>
> *Contrary to my first thoughts* this approach is more cumbersome than proving the proposition by induction. So, with less insight to the problem, but also with less effort to provide a solution the answer below is based upon induction.

---

This is an answer referring to the note of [Grumpy Parsnip](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2941/grumpy-parsnip). So, we put the focus on the $2\times2$-matrices

\begin{align*}
A_2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x_1 & x_2\\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\qquad
B_2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
x_3 & x_4
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align*}

$A_2$ and $B_2$ are upper left sub-matrices of $A$ and $B$ of the original question.
We assume integer entries and consider finite products of the above matrices
$$W=\prod_{j=1}^{n}X_j\qquad X_j\in\{A_2,B_2\}$$
We define $Re(W) := \prod_{j=1}^{n}X_{n+1-j}$, a kind of *reversed product* and show:

> The following statement valid:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \det\left(W+Re(W)\right)+\det\left(W-Re(W)\right) \equiv 0(4)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Observe that we *add* in (1) the determinants corresponding to the factor $(-1)^{m-1}$ for $(2m\times2m)$-matrices of *Grumpy Parsnips* note.

---

*Note:* To illustrate the *connection between the sub-matrices $A_2$ and $B_2$ and the matrices $A,B,C,D$* of the original question, see the picture with the corresponding automata below. The elements $x_{i,j}$ of a matrix are the labels of the edges from node $i$ to node $j$ of the automata. A matrix entry $1$ which is the *neutral element* with respect to multiplication is denoted with $\varepsilon$, the *neutral element* of *concatenation of words* of the formal language which are generated when walking along the edges of the automaton.

The automata clearly indicate the structural connection of the $(2\times 2)$ matrices $A_2,B_2$ and $(4\times 4)$ matrices $A,B,C,D$ making *Grumpy Parsnips* remark about *generalisation of the matrices* to $(2m\times 2m)$ matrices plausible, besides the factor $(-1)^{m-1}$ which was presumably a result of separate calculation.

[image]

[automata of transition matrices $A_2, B_2$ and $A,B,C,D$]

---

The following proof is done by *induction on the number $n$ of factors* of $W$

> **Induction base step** $(n=1)$
>
> In case $n=1$ we have to check two alternatives $W=A_2$ and $W=B_2$
>
> Case $W=A_2$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \det&\left(A_2+Re(A_2)\right)+ \det\left(A_2-Re(A_2)\right)\\
> &= \det(2\cdot A_2)+\det(0\cdot A_2)\\
> &=2^2\det(A_2)\equiv 0(4)
> \end{align*}

Observe, that $Re(W)=Re(A_2)=A_2$.

> Since the case $W=B_2$ is literally the same as $W=A_2$ the base step is proved.

Next, the

> **Induction hypotheses**
>
> We assume the statement $(1)$ is valid foreach $W=\prod_{j=1}^{n}X_j$ with $X_j\in\{A_2,B_2\}$.

So, let

> \begin{align*}
> W=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1} & w_{1,2}\\
> w_{2,1} & w_{2,2}
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \qquad
> Re(W)=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}^\ast & w_{1,2}^\ast\\
> w_{2,1}^\ast & w_{2,2}^\ast
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \end{align*}

Then we get

> \begin{align*}
> \det&\left(W+Re(W)\right)+\det\left(W-Re(W)\right)\\
> &=det\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}+w_{1,1}^\ast & w_{1,2}+w_{1,2}^\ast\\
> w_{2,1}+w_{2,1}^\ast & w_{2,2}+w_{2,2}^\ast
> \end{array}
> \right)
> +\det\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}-w_{1,1}^\ast & w_{1,2}-w_{1,2}^\ast\\
> w_{2,1}-w_{2,1}^\ast & w_{2,2}-w_{2,2}^\ast
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> &=(w_{1,1}+w_{1,1}^\ast)(w_{2,2}+w_{2,2}^\ast)-(w_{2,1}+w_{2,1}^\ast)(w_{1,2}+w_{1,2}^\ast)\\
> &+(w_{1,1}-w_{1,1}^\ast)(w_{2,2}-w_{2,2}^\ast)-(w_{2,1}-w_{2,1}^\ast)(w_{1,2}-w_{1,2}^\ast)\\
> &=2w_{1,1} w_{2,2}+2w_{1,1}^\ast w_{2,2}^\ast-2w_{1,2}w_{2,1}-2w_{1,2}^\ast w_{2,1}^\ast\\
> &\equiv 0(4)\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

And now we show the

> **Induction step** $(n \rightarrow n+1)$

We have to show that $(1)$ is valid for $WA_2$ and $WB_2$. It's sufficient to consider *right multiplication* with $A_2$ resp. $B_2$ since left multiplication is already subsumed by a proper choice of $W$.

> Case $WA_2$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> WA_2&=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1} & w_{1,2}\\
> w_{2,1} & w_{2,2}
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> x_1 & x_2\\
> 0 & 1
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> &=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}x_1 & w_{1,1}x_2+w_{1,2}\\
> w_{2,1}x_1 & w_{2,1}x_2+w_{2,2}
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> A_2Re(W)&=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> x_1 & x_2\\
> 0 & 1
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}^\ast & w_{1,2}^\ast\\
> w_{2,1}^\ast & w_{2,2}^\ast
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> &=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}^\ast x_1+w_{2,1}^\ast x_2 & w_{1,2}^\ast x_1+w_{2,2}^\ast x_2\\
> w_{2,1}^\ast & w_{2,2}^\ast
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \end{align*}

So, we get

> \begin{align*}
> \det&\left(WA_2+A_2Re(W)\right)+\det\left(WA_2-A_2Re(W)\right)\\
> &=det\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}x_1+w_{1,1}^\ast x_1+w_{2,1}^\ast x_2 & w_{1,1}x_2+w_{1,2}+w_{1,2}^\ast x_1+w_{2,2}^\ast x_2\\
> w_{2,1}x_1+w_{2,1}^\ast & w_{2,1}x_2+w_{2,2}+w_{2,2}^\ast
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> &+det\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}x_1-w_{1,1}^\ast x_1-w_{2,1}^\ast x_2 & w_{1,1}x_2+w_{1,2}-w_{1,2}^\ast x_1-w_{2,2}^\ast x_2\\
> w_{2,1}x_1-w_{2,1}^\ast & w_{2,1}x_2+w_{2,2}-w_{2,2}^\ast
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> &=(w_{1,1}x_1+w_{1,1}^\ast x_1+w_{2,1}^\ast x_2)(w_{2,1}x_2+w_{2,2}+w_{2,2}^\ast)\\
> &-(w_{2,1}x_1+w_{2,1}^\ast)(w_{1,1}x_2+w_{1,2}+w_{1,2}^\ast x_1+w_{2,2}^\ast x_2)\\
> &+(w_{1,1}x_1-w_{1,1}^\ast x_1-w_{2,1}^\ast x_2)(w_{2,1}x_2+w_{2,2}-w_{2,2}^\ast)\\
> &-(w_{2,1}x_1-w_{2,1}^\ast)(w_{1,1}x_2+w_{1,2}-w_{1,2}^\ast x_1-w_{2,2}^\ast x_2)\\
> &=(2w_{1,1} w_{2,2}+2w_{1,1}^\ast w_{2,2}^\ast-2w_{1,2}w_{2,1}-2w_{1,2}^\ast w_{2,1}^\ast)x_1\\
> &\equiv 0(4)
> \end{align*}

according to the induction hypothesis $(2)$.

> Case $WB_2$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> WB_2&=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1} & w_{1,2}\\
> w_{2,1} & w_{2,2}
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 0\\
> x_3 & x_4
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> &=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}+w_{1,2}x_3 & w_{1,2}x_4\\
> w_{2,1}+w_{2,2}x_3 & w_{2,2}x_4
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> B_2Re(W)&=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 0\\
> x_3 & x_4
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}^\ast & w_{1,2}^\ast\\
> w_{2,1}^\ast & w_{2,2}^\ast
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> &=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}^\ast  & w_{1,2}^\ast\\
> w_{1,1}^\ast x_3+w_{2,1}^\ast x_4 & w_{1,2}^\ast x_3+w_{2,2}^\ast x_4
> \end{array}
> \right)
> \end{align*}

So, we get

> \begin{align*}
> \det&\left(WB_2+B_2Re(W)\right)+\det\left(WB_2-B_2Re(W)\right)\\
> &=det\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}+w_{1,2}x_3+w_{1,1}^\ast & w_{1,2}x_4+w_{1,2}^\ast\\
> w_{2,1}+w_{2,2}x_3+w_{1,1}^\ast x_3+w_{2,1}^\ast x_4 & w_{2,2}x_4+w_{1,2}^\ast x_3+w_{2,2}^\ast x_4
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> &+det\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> w_{1,1}+w_{1,2}x_3-w_{1,1}^\ast & w_{1,2}x_4-w_{1,2}^\ast\\
> w_{2,1}+w_{2,2}x_3-w_{1,1}^\ast x_3-w_{2,1}^\ast x_4 & w_{2,2}x_4-w_{1,2}^\ast x_3-w_{2,2}^\ast x_4
> \end{array}
> \right)\\
> &=(w_{1,1}+w_{1,2}x_3+w_{1,1}^\ast)(w_{2,2}x_4+w_{1,2}^\ast x_3+w_{2,2}^\ast x_4)\\
> &-(w_{2,1}+w_{2,2}x_3+w_{1,1}^\ast x_3+w_{2,1}^\ast x_4)(w_{1,2}x_4+w_{1,2}^\ast)\\
> &+(w_{1,1}+w_{1,2}x_3-w_{1,1}^\ast)(w_{2,2}x_4-w_{1,2}^\ast x_3-w_{2,2}^\ast x_4)\\
> &-(w_{2,1}+w_{2,2}x_3-w_{1,1}^\ast x_3-w_{2,1}^\ast x_4)(w_{1,2}x_4-w_{1,2}^\ast)\\
> &=(2w_{1,1} w_{2,2}+2w_{1,1}^\ast w_{2,2}^\ast-2w_{1,2}w_{2,1}-2w_{1,2}^\ast w_{2,1}^\ast)x_4\\
> &\equiv 0(4)
> \end{align*}

according to the induction hypothesis $(2)$ which completes the proof by induction.

---

*Note:* A proof by induction of the original answer could be done in the same way (with considerably more effort :-) )

Comment: thanks for the answer. Your counterexample in the 2 by 2 case is to a different problem! In that case, the conjecture is that the sum of the two determinants is a multiple of four, not the difference.

Comment: I still need to read through the rest, but it looks nice, and you clearly put a lot of effort into it.!

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: Ah, yes you're right! These are good news! :-) So, I can try to proceed with the proof. I will do it within the next few days and then I correct my answer. Best regards.

Comment: Since, the bounty expires in a few hours, I am awarding it to you. Hopefully this doesn't lessen your diligence in searching for a proof. :)

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: First of all thanks for the bounty and of course I'm working on a solution (I like small challenges :-)) Currently I have a partial solution for the easy stuff. Please expect an update next weekend.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: I've completed my answer, which hopefully pleases you. Best regards.

Comment: Nice. Perhaps some similar induction will work for the 4x4 case, although the exact same argument does not seem to work.